# DataTables Initialized/Executed too Early on Dynamic HTML Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a function that creates an HTML table based on an array. Once the HTML table is finished being created, I then want to call jQuery DataTables to render the table.

However, this doesn't work. I get the "No data Available in Table" line whenever I do this, and my table data appears. But, as soon as I click a filter for it, all the `<td>` HTML data disappears. I've checked my table's HTML, it's correctly defined, has all the necessary tags, and matches with what my function creates.

From what I've read, the issue lies with the DataTables function firing too early. I confirmed this by using the `setTimeout` function- it creates the table perfectly and with no errors. However, this solution isn't scalable and would cause the same problem once the data expands.

I've tried fixing this by using a callback (DataTables still fires too early, I used `renderTable(function(){$('#divtable').DataTable();}`), and a promise (it still fires too early, I tried to use `function.done()...`). How can I call the render function as only when the HTML table div is finished updating?

Here is my (shortened) code:

HTML Table render:

```
function renderTable() {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var tableRow = '';
        tableRow += '<tr><td class="ID">' + array[i].id + '</td><td>' + array[i].date + '</td><td>' + array[i].total + '</td><td><input type=button class="editValues" value="Edit Values" /></td></tr>';
        $("#divtable > tbody").append(tableRow);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    renderTable();
    $('#divtable').DataTable();
}
```

Comment: Are you using an ajax request? I think we need to see more of the code.

Comment: where you get the data?

Comment: The data comes from a local PouchDB database. Each data entry can be treated as a basic array with attributes, so fetching the date element from the database can be retrieved as `array[i].date`, etc. The table render function iterates through each entry and gets each attribute in order to make a table row for it. That part of the code works with no issues, it's the handling of the result (delay datatables function until the DOM finishes updating) that I can't get right.